# App(...): Nothing was returned from render, when routing different roles of user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use this function to check role of the logged in user.

```
export function getUserRole() {
  return (
    localStorage.getItem('token') &&
    jwtDecode(localStorage.getItem('token')).role
  )
}
```

in my index.js I have $(this)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.role = getUserRole()
  }

  render() {
    if (this.role === 'member') {
      return (
        <Provider store={userStore}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="App">
              <Switch>
                <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" />
                <Auth path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />

                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

But I got this error?

> App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

I'm not sure should I put the getUserRole function the the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling exactly what it means literally. Since you've added an `if (this.role === 'member')`, there will be no `return` if it's not a member and there must be a `return` within `render` method

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the unauthenticated scenario also.So,in that case, you should update your render method to return the following:

```
render() {
  if (this.role !== 'member') {
    return (<div>Unauthenticated</div>);
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={userStore}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className='App'>
          <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from='/' to='/dashboard' />
            <Auth path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />

            <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```